# firebase - App Check fails when accessing database from callable cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, firebase-app-check

I recently enabled [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) for my firebase app and enforced it on both my cloud functions and database. The cloud function workflow is behaving correctly. However, I can no longer access the database from the function. A minimal version of my callable function looks something like this:

```js
exports.myFunc = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const adminApp = admin.initializeApp();
  const ref = adminApp.database().ref('some-node');
  
  if (context.app === undefined) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'failed-precondition',
      'The function must be called from an App Check verified app.',
    );
  }

  try {
    return (await ref.orderByKey().equalTo('foo').get()).exists()
  } catch(exc) {
    console.error(exc);
  }
});
```

This used to work before App Check, but now it fails and I see this in the logs:

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Invalid appcheck token (https://my-project-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/)
> Error: Error: Client is offline.

Seems like I need to do something extra to get the `admin` app to pass App Check verification down to the database, but I haven't been able to find any documentation on this yet. I also tried using the app instance from `functions.app.admin` instead of initializing a new one, but this didn't help.

I have the latest version of the packages:

```
"firebase-admin": "^9.10.0"
"firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
```

Comment: *firebaser here* That looks unexpected at first glance, so I'm going to check with the engineering team to see what's going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The behavior you're seeing is *not* how it's supposed to work, and we've been able to reproduce it. Thanks for the clear report, and sorry you encountered this.

If you (re)install the Firebase Admin SDK today, you won't be experiencing this same problem as we've fixed the problem in the `@firebase/database` dependency (in this [PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/5082)).

If you're (still) experiencing the problem, you can check if you have the correct `@firebase/database` dependency by running:

```
npm ls @firebase/database
```

results look something like this:

```
temp-admin@1.0.0 /Users/you/repos/temp-admin
└─┬ firebase-admin@9.11.0
  └── @firebase/database@0.10.8
```

If your `@firebase/database` version is lower than `0.10.8`, you'll have to reinstall the Admin SDK, for example by deleting your `node_modules` directory and your `package-lock.json` file and running `npm install` again. This may also update other dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt action. Looking forward to the solution or workaround.

Comment: Thanks, Frank! waiting for the solution on our side as well :D We are excited to be able to use app-check in our app.

Comment: *Firebaser here.*

The fix is now available in `@firebase/database@0.10.8`. Thanks for bringing this issue to our attention!